# How to determine the diagonalizability of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I am wondering there are any simple rules to determine whether a matrix $X$ is diagonalizable. I find from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable) that tell me:

$X$ is diagonalizable over the field $F$ if it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues in $F$.

However, I found an example $X=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1 & 1  \\
   1 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$. $X$ has only one eigenvalue, but $X$ is diagonalizable as $X=VDV^{-1}$, where

$V=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   -0.7071 & 0.7071  \\
   0.7071 & 0.7071  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$
and
$D=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0 & 0  \\
   0 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

Could anyone tell me, given an arbitrary matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, how to determine whether there exists $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $X=VDV^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two (equivalent) criteria: $A$ is diagonalisable over a field $K$ if and only if

- The *characteristic polynomial* $\chi_A(x)$ splits into a product of linear factors and for each factor $(x-\lambda)^m$, corresponding to  an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of (algebraic) multiplicity $m$ and an eigenspace $E_\lambda$, $$\dim E_\lambda\enspace\text{(geometric multiplicity)}=m \enspace\text{(algebraic multiplicity)}.$$
- The *minimal polynomial* $p_A(x)$ splits into a product of *distinct* linear factors. In other words, the eigenvalues are *simple* roots of the minimal polynomial.

Note in case of $n$ distinct eigenvalues, all these values are simple roots of $\;\chi_A(x)=p_A(x)$ and the eigenspaces have all dimension $1$.